# Python 3 Type Annotations conditional function return type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a function that will return either a valid `pwd.struct_passwd` or `None`.

What would be the best way to annotate this function's return type since it could be either/or?

```
import pwd

def user_lookup(user_name: str):
    try:
        return pwd.getpwnam(user_name)
    except KeyError:
        return None


# this would return -> pwd.struct_passwd
user_lookup('a_valid_username') 

# this would produce a KeyError and return -> None
user_lookup('a_nonexistant_user')
```

Comment: In general, you use `Union`, for the specific case of returning some type or `None`, you can use `Optional`, so `Union[str, None]` is equivalent to `Optional[str]`

Comment: i searched but didnt know exactly what to look for and this is exactly what i needed, thank you